# Are org's logs available elsewhere different from EventLogFile?

Tags: apex, api, logging, eventlogfile

We are currently investigating when Apex classes/pages/triggers were last run, and the EventLogFile object was the suggested as the way of retrieving relevant data.

But I wonder if the org's usage logs (not debug logs) can be retrieved from other source?
I did some digging but couldn't find anything relevant so far. Would you mind helping me out on this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: EventLogFile is the only out of the box "log" for the kind of information you're after. What are you trying to accomplish by pulling this info, perhaps there's another option? Please edit your question.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
The main intent is to identify which Apex classes/pages/triggers are no longer being used. A proposed way to achieve it is by analyzing the logs. 
However, we could only find the EventLogFile object, and this is a paid addon that allows the storage of logs with a 30-day limit only. So we are investigating if there is any other way or place from which we could retrieve such logs

Comment: A weaker but free alternative is [MetadataComponentDependency](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/280085/soql-for-winter-20-where-is-this-used-functionality/280601). With manual review of results, you might be able to prune unused assets.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will take a look into it as well